# How to show CSS loader while multiple-redirects are completed at the client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http-redirect, preloader

I'm building a website where I recommend products to my end-users following a [link like this one](http://www.blipadeal.com/site.php?link=31871551&s=5) (blipadeal is my external provider, I don't have control over this server).

If you follow the link you can see the user is redirected through at least 3 separate domains which leaves a non-desirable user experience.

**I'd like to show a personalised "loading" page with my brand, removing it ONLY at the END of the last redirect** avoiding the impression of multiple jumps to the user, any recommendations on how to achieve this at the client side preferable using Angular?

I've tried:

- Using Angular $http but no luck due CORS (I don't have control over the external server)
- Using JQuery to know when the page is loaded but no luck as there is an intermediate HTTP 200 before the following HTTP redirects
- Server side solution (to proxy the calls and avoid CORS issues) is not really an option as  I need to ensure the user referrals from my site are tracked
- iFrame solution based on a timeout hiding the frame for X seconds while all redirects are completed is not ideal as I may get into Branding problems with my Providers (I need to handover the user in a new browser tab with the correct page title and headers)

Thanks,

Comment: If the browser is taking the user to a different page, let alone domain, then it's outside of realm of influence of what you can do with the code on your page (including Angular, jQuery, etc...).

Comment: Thanks New Dev, I was hoping to do something similar to what Yipit does, if you follow this [link](http://yipit.com/aff/click/?deal=WrTy3Qfz&key=F38tgRdb&subid1=web-browse&subid2=new-for-you), there are around 3 redirections that are masked before redirecting the user to the final URL, any idea of how that could have been achieved?

Comment: If I understand correctly, browsers wait to render anything new (i.e. the existing page remains) if the response from the server is an HTTP 302 redirect (which is what happens with yipit). That's clearly not your case, since blipit returns HTTP 200

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications New Dev, based on that I implemented one part of the work on my server side to workaround the HTTP 200 and leaving the redirections on the client side to ensure the tracking still happens.